# How do I get todolist (abstract spoon) working?

Tags: wine

I wish to run [todolist 6.3.8](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx) on Ubuntu 11.10.

I have installed the latest wine and winetricks. 
I have tried running:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx 
winetricks vcrun2005 
winetricks vcrun2008 
winetricks vcrun6
```

Which installed all of the components.

When I went to run todolist.exe, it started fine with the "first time wizard" (asking me where to save definitions and what file to open first), and then it stopped saying

> "the program todolist.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs
>   to close. we are sorry for the inconvenience".

What can I do to make this (great) software work on ubuntu?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!